# Flatten an array object to single object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I'm using [ChartKick](https://chartkick.com/vue) to represent some data in the graphs in Multiple series line chart.  The required format is:

```
let data = [
   { name: 'sharry', data: { '2008-08-02': 10006097, '2018-08-03': 10670, etc }},
   { name: 'stuart', data: { '2018-08-01' :1401231321, '2018-08-04': 2500000000, etc }}
];
```

The data I get from the database is:

```
let user_usage = [
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-02":10006097 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-03":10670 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-05":5800000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-07":10789000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-08":1033000000 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-01":1401231321 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-04":2500000000 } }
];
```

I've been trying for 2 days to get the database response into the required format above Any help greatly appreciated guys.  Here is what I have so far. I'm using Ramda but ES6 is fine to use:

```
let chartdata = [];
let u = R.groupBy(R.prop('name'))(user_usage);

Object.keys(u).forEach((name, index) => {
  chartdata.push({ name , data: {} });
  let usage = u[name];

  Object.keys(usage).forEach(row => {
    let data = usage[row].data;
    let date = Object.keys(data)[0];
    let total = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
    chartdata[index].data = Object.assign({}, {`${date}: ${total}`};
  });
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with what the OP wants @anttud? (hint: is **IS** valid)

Comment: @JaromandaX is correct

Comment: considering you've produced the required result @AnkitAgarwal it wasn't hard to be correct :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.reduce()` with `Object.assign()` so that you can assign the `data` object to the existing item of the accumulator.

```js
let user_usage = [
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-02":10006097 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-03":10670 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-05":5800000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-07":10789000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-08":1033000000 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-01":1401231321 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-04":2500000000 } }
];
var res = user_usage.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var existItem = acc.find(({name}) => name === item.name);
  if(existItem){
    Object.assign(existItem.data,item.data);
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, 
[]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: there's a little redundancy and repetition in your code ... `var res = user_usage.reduce((acc, item) => {
  var existItem = acc.find(({name}) => name === item.name);
  if (existItem){
    Object.assign(existItem.data,item.data);
  } else {
    acc.push(item);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);`

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. Appreciate that. Updated with your suggested code

Comment: Thanks for posting :)

Comment: @molinto glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {};
user_usage.forEach(function(e){
    if(!obj[e.name]){
       obj[e.name] = e.data;
    } else {
       obj[e.name] = Object.assign(obj[e.name], e.data)
    }
});
var array = Object.keys(obj).map(function(e){return {name: e, data: obj[e]}})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
let user_usage = [
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-02":10006097 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-03":10670 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-05":5800000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-07":10789000 } },
  { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-08":1033000000 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-01":1401231321 } },
  { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-04":2500000000 } }
];

let data = user_usage.reduce((a, c) => {
  let key = Object.keys(c.data)[0];
  let found = a.find(v => v.name === c.name);
  if(found){
    found.data[key] = c.data[key];
  }else{
    a.push(c);
  }
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(data);
```

Comment: lots of undefined in your output

Comment: Thanks @titus, getting lots of 'undefined' when running though

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I've just notice that, is probably because I'm pushing references instead of new objects.

Comment: @molinto fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()` and `Map()` for a more efficient solution:

```js
let user_usage = [ { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-02":10006097 } }, { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-03":10670 } }, { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-05":5800000 } }, { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-07":10789000 } }, { "name":"stuart", "data": { "2018-08-08":1033000000 } }, { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-01":1401231321 } }, { "name":"sharry", "data": { "2018-08-04":2500000000 } } ];
var map = new Map();
user_usage.forEach((obj)=>{
  if(map.has(obj.name)){
    var mapObject = map.get(obj.name);
    Object.assign(mapObject.data, obj.data);
    map.set(obj.name ,mapObject); 
  } else{
    map.set(obj.name, Object.assign({},obj));
  }
});
let result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ramda example too for reference:

```
pipe(
  groupBy(prop('name')),
  map(pipe(pluck('data'), mergeAll)),
)
```